# How can we eliminate duplicates form the unsorted comma separated list by using regex in PERL

Tags: regex, perl

For Example, we have `$list1` var as -

```
$list1 = "GET, POST, GET, DELETE";
```

Expected output -

```
GET,POST,DELETE
```

Comment: Are you really insistent that regex is the tool for this?  It would be simpler and more natural if that wasn't in your requirements.

Answer (score 7):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my $list1 = "GET, POST, GET, DELETE";

print join ",", uniq split /\W+/, $list1;
```

output

```
GET,POST,DELETE
```

Comment: The expected output only has `,`, not `, `.

Comment: @simbabque: So change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `(\b\w+),\s*(?=.*\1)` by nothing

Comment: It doesn't help if you have `GET, GET, GET, POST`.

Comment: Well, it's still problematic.  What of `GET, POST, GET, POST`?  What of `GET, POST, GET, POST, GET, POST`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

my $list1 = "GET, POST, GET, DELETE";

my @list = split(/, /, $list1);
my %hash;
@hash{@list} = '';

print join(", ", keys %hash), "\n";
```

Output:

```
DELETE, POST, GET
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %seen
print join ',', grep !$seen{$_}++, split /, /, $list1;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
print join ',', uniq, split /, /, $list1;
```